# Does the Octahedron graph have a Hamilton's cycle? an Euler's cycle?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I would be glad to find out the paths. and how to prove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope it can help you

Hamiltonian cycles
[Hamiltonian Cycles on Symmetrical Graphs](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~sequin/PAPERS/Bridges04_HamilPaths.pdf)

[image]

[Eulerian Cycle](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulerianCycle.html)

[image]